# 仮想マシンバックアップを故意に失敗させたい

Tags: azure

タイトルの通りなのですが、MicrosoftのAzure上でVMバックアップをわざと失敗させて、エラーを出したいのです。

何か方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Backupは、Running状態のVMバックアップにインターネット接続が必要です。
NSGでOutBound通信を禁止し、インターネット接続できない状態でバックアップを実行すればエラーとなります。

以下のサイトに記載があります。

[https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare#a-namenetwork-connectivityaネットワーク接続](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare#a-namenetwork-connectivitya%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A)

> 拡張機能が VM スナップショットを管理するためには、Azure のパブリック IP アドレスへの接続が必要です。 適切なインターネット接続を利用できない場合、VM からの HTTP 要求はタイムアウトになり、バックアップ操作は失敗します。(たとえば、ネットワーク セキュリティ グループ (NSG) を使用して)デプロイにアクセス制限が適用されている場合は、次のいずれかのオプションを選択して、バックアップ トラフィックの明確なパスを指定する必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。当初はProvisionGuestAgentの値をFalseにして、‌​VMがVMエージェントを認識しない方法で‌​できるのではないかと考えていましたが、こ‌​の方法でポートを絞ってインターネット接続できないようにすれば良さそうです。